# How to wrap text in AngularJS with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

This should be an easy answer but I'm not getting it here.

```
<span ng-show="myResults !=null && !isShowDetails" class="yourScore">
  YOUR SCORE (best 4) : {{myResults.fullSumBest}} pts - total: {{user.userScore}} pts 
  <span style="float:right"  ng-click="showDetails()">
     [ + ] show details 
  </span>
</span>
```

When I resize the screen down the text doesn't overflow it just gives me ... and cuts off the text and the score.

Things I've tried off the top of my head:

```
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  width: 100%;
```

I'd prefer not use @media here to lower the font size unless absolutely needed. Ideally it would just wrap down to the line below.

Comment: To float a span you must set it (at least) to `display: inline-block`, since default for span's is `inline`

Comment: By doing that it gets rid of the ... but is still taking off text off the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked perfect. It had inherited this from Ion-item

```
white-space: none;
```

and I just needed to add this to the class for the span:

```
white-space: normal;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you need.

So in the below example I tried simulating what I thought might be the problem. I am using the angular filter `limitTo` to restrict the length of the characters, if you want to change this length, all you need to do is change the value of the `15` in the below code to your desired length. I also added some extra code, please either use it or ignore it, for the layout issue. I set the parent span to `position:relative;display:block` so that it will take the entire width of the window, the second child span I gave `position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;` so that it gets fixed on the right side, finally I added the CSS `display:block;padding-right;` to the first child span, so that it takes the entire width, and the padding is to take into account the absolute positioned span. Please let me know if this fixes your issue.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
    <span style="position:relative;display:block;" ng-show="myResults !=null && !isShowDetails" class="yourScore">
    <span style="position:relative;display:block;padding-right:120px;">{{'YOUR SCORE (best 4) : '+myResults.fullSumBest+' pts - total: '+user.userScore+' pts' | limitTo : limit}}</span>

      <span style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;" ng-init="bool = false;limit=15;" ng-click="bool=!bool;limit=bool ? 100000 : 15">
         {{bool ? '[ + ] hide details ' : '[ + ] show details '}}
      </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot as well but I found a better fix to just enter this into the class:
  white-space: normal;

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure if it's the "better" fix until I do a little more responsive things. I'm still going to try yours out as well! Thank you!